# Special characters not encoded properly

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

## The Issue :

Arabic/Hebrew/non-latin characters,when extracted from database/dynamic source engine, are not properly rendered, instead are shown as '??????'
[image: click to enlarge]
[image]

## The Story (debug steps) :

Whenever a user saves something (let's say meta keywords as shown above) to database, it is saved normally with correct encoding, but after saving the characters are not rendered properly but instead as '?????' due to encoding problem.

All the files are UTF-8 Encoded, the headers are sent as UTF-8,the database collation is utf8_general_ci,meta charset is set to utf-8 and the connection to database is also utf-8.

Saving the keywords directly via MySQL console or PHPMyAdmin will render the same result, thus the issue is with showing the characters and not saving them.

Getting the keywords manually using mysql_query + mysql_fetch_array will solve the issue, thus the issue is caused by the function used to get the keywords (or the file containing this function).

## The Solution :

Can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11020511/437912)

Best Regards

Comment: Possibly you use htmlentities with wrong encoding?

Comment: yes i use htmlentities but with the correct encoding, i even tried to remove it and resave, but still it goes wrong,edited the main post with more info

Comment: Do you make any data transformation before the output?

Comment: if you mean rechecking and removing slashes (for example) before output, then no, otherwise please explain briefly

Comment: I mean that standard PHP functions used for strings processing are not utf-8 safe. These functions can destroy your data. You need to use mb_* functions or some other methods. Also don't forget to set encoding for mb_* functions before using them.

Comment: mbstring isn't used in this project at all, also the output is directly coming out from the database

Comment: when SELECTing use the BINARY keyword `SELECT BINARY utf8_column, ...` see if that helps

Comment: @SAFAD A little unclear. If you view the data through phpMyAdmin then you still see the wrong data?

Comment: @Karolis no i see them correctly, i found the problem, the script uses  $globals['keywords'] it seems if i replace that with direct mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array the data show up correctly, funny thing i can't find where and how $globals are defined O_O

Comment: @SAFAD I think that function `makequery()` uses different database connection identifier which does not set connection charset (or set it incorrectly).

Comment: @karolis 
 $result = mysql_query($query, $conn); while $conn is the connection variable : $conn = mysql_connect($globals['server'], $globals['user'], $globals['password']);

Comment: @SAFAD I think you need this after the connection: `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution :

It seems like the editor used to save the files as UTF8 had a bug and did not save them properly encoded.
Switching to [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and saving all the files as UTF8 has solved the issue.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL check if your tables and also columns are set to utf8. If you've created all database structure and changed the database coding to utf8 afterwards it does not change coding of existing tables and columns. It just sets the default coding for newly created relations.

Comment: the entire database and tables have been created UTF-8 since the start

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your pages are XHTML, don't use htmlentities() (even with correct encoding) on XHTML pages. The only characters that should be converted to entity references in XHTML(or XML) documents are &, ", <, >

```
function xmlEntities( $s ) {
    return str_replace( array( '&', '"', '<', '>' ),
                    array( '&amp;', '&quot;', '&lt;', '&gt;' ), $s );
}
```